# How do you physical download and start using Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

This is a must-answer question that needs answered for a generation of coders.

I know to go to the website, but how do you actually download Backbone and start coding.

Most tutorials leave out this stage.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The [home page](http://backbonejs.org) has a **Downloads & Dependencies** section right at the top that tells you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Most Backbone code I see on stackoverflow is a real mess lacking structure which is a shame. But the flexibility in the right hands is also a very strong point that is why larger companies still use frequently choose Backbone whilst newbies would go for something with a little more magic out the box like Angular or Ember.

This is what I recommend in a general sense:

[Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for tasks - grunt might be easier as it is more widely used still. Main tasks would be:
- build (compile and minify your code and css) and bundle into a build folder
- server (runs local server or a server from a build folder)
- test (if you have unit or functional tests)

Next you have an index.html file which contains an app wrapper and a single [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)  call the the entry point of your code.

My folder structure would look something like this:

```
server/
server/server.js

public/
public/app/app.js
public/app/modules/
public/app/extensions/

public/assets/
public/assets/css/
public/assets/images/

public/packages/

public/index.html

dist/
dist/<env>/public/assets/
dist/<env>/public/app/app.min.js (or app.js depending on env)

package.json
Gruntfile.js
```

A colleague's boilerplate is probably the closest to my ideal setup in the public domain: https://github.com/mderrick/backbone-boilerplate

There is also marionette: http://marionettejs.com/